# Is it possible to use a TikZ matrix along a chain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

Is it possible to use a TikZ `matrix` along a `chain`?

The following code attempts to create a chain consisting of a `node`, a `matrix`, and another `node`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
  \node [on chain] {XYZ};

  \matrix [on chain]
  {
    \node {A}; \\
    \node {B}; \\
    \node {C}; \\
  };

  \node [on chain] {123};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, if I try to compile, I get the error "Package pgf Error: No shape named chain-2 is known."  (Interestingly, if I remove the final node so that nothing follows the matrix, then it compiles without error.)  Why does this error occur?

Of course, it is straightforward enough to use the `positioning` library directly.  So, mostly, I am interested in this question for its own sake; I don't have an important, specific use in mind where chains of matrices would be critical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nodes on the chains are named as `(chainname-#)` but this naming scheme is not provided to the matrix (seems like a bug). So the safest way is to name your matrix nodes on the chain explicitly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
  \node [on chain] {XYZ};
  \node [on chain] {123};
  \node [on chain,matrix of nodes]  (chain-3) {    A \\    B \\    C \\  };
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion of explicitly naming the matrix with `(chain-3)` does indeed work.  However, when I try naming the chain in your code with `start chain=mychain` and `on chain=mychain`, I get the same error as before unless I continue to explicitly name the matrix with `(mychain-3)`.  Is something more going on here?

Comment: Thinking back to this question, I am not sure that I understand why there is a naming clash between chains and matrices.   If I try `\matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes] { A \\ B \\ C \\ D \\ }; \draw[fill,blue] (mat-1) circle (2pt);`, I get the error that "No shape named `mat-1` is known."  Why does this then conflict with the way a chain is named, if `mat-1` doesn't appear to be used in ordinary matrix construction?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung You need to use `(mat-1-1)` even though it's a vector. The problem is that the matrix is full of nodes but none of them gets the proper chain name. So it needs to be explicitly stated. But you are right I should have mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: My above comment wasn't very clear.  I was trying to use the `circle` at `mat-1` to show that a matrix named `mat` doesn't actually define any point named `mat-1`, which is indeed confirmed by the error message that I got.  Given this, then, I don't understand why there is a naming clash between chain names and matrix names.  Why doesn't TikZ just assign the proper chain name (e.g., `chain-3`) to the matrix itself (as opposed to hoping that one of the nodes within the matrix will have the proper name for inclusion on the chain)?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung I don't know exactly the problem but the problem with such syntax is that TikZ always decides what to do by scanning the next character. And most probably `-` character directly steers the algorithm to matrix part of the code. But there is no matrix node with the name `chain` such that TikZ can keep on parsing the particular subentry e.g. (chain-3-5) etc. So it knows that it's a matrix but cannot parse it since (chain-3) is missing the column part. That's probably why it gets confused.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, and I worked around it by putting the matrix inside a nested `tikzpicture` i.e.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
  \node [on chain] {XYZ};

  \node [on chain] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix
      {
        \node {A}; \\
        \node {B}; \\
        \node {C}; \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
  \node [on chain] {123};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've stumbled upon this problem a few times myself, I investigated.

And yes, `alias` doesn't work on matrices because they simply never get aliased.

The `alias = <alias>` key accumulates aliases into `\tikz@alias` in the form of

```
\pgfnodealias{<alias>}{<name>}
```

and when the node has been finally constructed and when `<name>` (i.e. the “real” name of the node/matrix/coordinate) is final this `\tikz@alias` is executed.

It is simply missing from the matrix code. In this small example I didn't notice any adverse effects.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\ExplSyntaxOn \makeatletter
\tl_replace_once:Nnn
  \tikz@do@matrix@cont
  { \tikz@node@finish }
  { \tikz@alias \tikz@node@finish }
\makeatother \ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\node [on chain] {XYZ};
\matrix [on chain] {
  \node {A}; \\
  \node {B}; \\
  \node {C}; \\};
\node [on chain] {123};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: → [Logged as #1224.](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1224)