# Giving a `matrix` node an `alias`

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

[This TeX.sx question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60032/5699) asks if is it possible to use a TikZ matrix along a chain. The error that occurs when one tries to do so is `Package pgf Error: No shape named chain-3 is known.`, and a way to circumvent it is to manually give the matrix node that name.

If the node is already used with a name it was given before making it a matrix, it can be tempting to give it an alias, like below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
  \node [on chain] {XYZ};
  \node [on chain,alias=Foo] {123};
  \node [on chain,matrix of nodes,alias=Bar]  (chain-3) {    A \\    B \\    C \\  };
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \fill (Foo) circle (2pt);
  \fill (Bar) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alas, this doesn't work, as it seems matrix nodes simply ignore the alias option -- which probably explains why they don't get the `chain-i` name when used in a chain.

Is there a way to give a `matrix` `node` an `alias`? *Note: I'm using PGF version 2.10, which is rather up-to-date. If this behaviour is fixed in a later release, please let me know.*

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [alias=Foo] (regularnode) {123};
  \node [matrix of nodes,alias=Bar] (matrixnode) {A\\B\\C\\};
  \fill (Foo) circle (2pt);
  \fill (Bar) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works perfectly for `Foo` (the regular node), but the last `\fill` command gives `ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named Bar is known.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Updated solution

A more general solution defining the `matrix on chain` style to fix the naming bug with matrix on chain (the result is the same as below).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,matrix,fit}
\tikzset{
  matrix on chain/.style={
    on chain=#1,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{\node[fit=(\tikzlastnode),inner sep=0] (\tikzchaincurrent){};}
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=foo going below,start chain=bar going right]
  \node [on chain] {ooo};
  \node [on chain, alias=Foobar] {123};
  \node [matrix on chain, matrix of nodes,name=Bar] {A\\B\\C\\};
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \node [on chain=foo] {XXX};
  \node [matrix on chain=foo,matrix of nodes,name=Foo] {A\\B\\C\\};
  \node [on chain=foo] {XXX};
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \fill[red] (Foo) circle (2pt);
  \fill[red] (Bar) circle (2pt);
  \fill[blue] (Bar-1-1) circle (2pt);
  \draw[green!50!black] (Bar.south west) -- (Bar.south east);
  \draw[red!50!black,very thick] (Foo.south west) -- (Foo.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## First solution

Here is a solution (a mix between **JLDiaz's answer**, **percusse's comment** and my idea) using automatically  the `fit` library (*the example is more complex to test with two chains*).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,matrix,fit}
\tikzset{
  chainalias/.style={name=#1,append after command={
      \pgfextra{\node[fit=(\tikzlastnode),inner sep=0] (\tikzchaincurrent){};}
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=foo going below,start chain=bar going right]
  \node [on chain] {ooo};
  \node [on chain, alias=Foo] {123};
  \node [on chain, matrix of nodes,chainalias=Bar] {A\\B\\C\\};
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \node [on chain=foo] {XXX};
  \node [on chain=foo, matrix of nodes,chainalias=Foo] {A\\B\\C\\};
  \node [on chain=foo] {XXX};
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \fill[red] (Foo) circle (2pt);
  \fill[red] (Bar) circle (2pt);
  \fill[blue] (Bar-1-1) circle (2pt);
  \draw[green!50!black] (Bar.south west) -- (Bar.south east);
  \draw[red!50!black,thick] (Foo.south west) -- (Foo.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `fit` to "clone" a node is a smart move!

Comment: Just explicitly aliasing via `\pgfextra{\pgfnodealias{\tikzchaincurrent}{\tikzlastnode}}` should do the trick, too. Or, well, [fixing the matrix code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668238).

Answer (score 9):

A silly idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain
]
  \node [on chain] {XYZ};
  \node [on chain, alias=Foo] {123};
  \node [on chain, matrix of nodes ] (chain-3) {  A \\    B \\    C \\  };
  \coordinate (Bar) at (chain-3);
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \fill[red] (Foo) circle (2pt);
  \fill[red] (Bar) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

**UPDATE**: Since the OP requested to be able to access `Bar` anchors, I had another silly idea: give the name `Bar` to the matrix, and the name `chain-3` to the "alias" coordinate. This works because the name `chain-3` is required only to position the next element of the chain, and knowing the center is enough. Then:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start chain
]
  \node [on chain] {XYZ};
  \node [on chain, alias=Foo] {123};
  \node [on chain, matrix of nodes ] (Bar) {  A \\    B \\    C \\  };
  \coordinate (chain-3) at (Bar);
  \node [on chain] {$\alpha\beta\gamma$};
  \fill[red] (Foo) circle (2pt);
  \fill[red] (Bar) circle (2pt);
  \fill[blue] (Bar-1-1) circle (2pt);
  \draw[green!50!black] (Bar.south west) -- (Bar.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Yup, that works when you access the center of the node, but not if you need to access its anchors: `\fill[red] (Bar.north east) circle (2pt);` or `\fill[red] (Bar.73) circle (2pt);` won't work. I don't know if there is a way to create a "clone" node, that works like a `coordinate`, but also copies all the anchors from the original node. Basically an "alias" shape. If that existed, using it instead of your `coordinate` would solve the problem indeed.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron Updated answer :-)

Comment: Sneaky! You can automate it via `\tikzset{mychainalias/.style={append after command={coordinate (chain-#1) at (\tikzlastnode)}}}` then add the option `mychainalias=3` to the matrix for sweeping it under the rug. But if the matrix is wide enough you might get into trouble.

Comment: @percusse As a more general solution, for the case of wide matrices, the "alias" should be `\coordinate (chain-3) at (Bar.east);` but unfortunately the cardinal point depends on the growth direction of the chain.